# Carla Data Extraction Key Error with ROSBAGS

Tags: ros, carla

I'm pretty new to ROS and Carla, but I'm doing a project on imitation learning that needs to extract data from ROS. I'm using this library [rosbags](https://ternaris.gitlab.io/rosbags/index.html) to retrieve data.

With other datas like image and speed, I could easily extract and deserialize with the following code.

```py
from rosbags.rosbag2 import Reader
from rosbags.serde import deserialize_cdr

def print_data(topic):
    with Reader('carla_data') as reader:
        for i, (connection, timestamp, rawdata) in enumerate(reader.messages()):
            if connection.topic == topic:
                msg = deserialize_cdr(rawdata, connection.msgtype)
                print(i, msg)
                break
```

I have data from topics from ROS for the following:
[image: tpoics from ROS]

Everything works fine except for the topic **/carla/ego_vehicle/vehicle_control_cmd_manual** which gives an error like this
[image]

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have those message files installed on the computer you’re running this on? If not, they need to be installed via `apt`(or whatever package manager you use.

It messages are installed you should be importing them in your Python file, so it has a message description to work off. e.g. `from carla_msgs.msg import CarlaEgoVehicleControl`

Comment: I'm using windows so I'm not really sure what or how to install. I've tried `pip install carla` but didn't work

Comment: @Jerry pip is really just for Python packages so that’s why it didn’t work. Have you followed these [install instructions?](https://carla.readthedocs.io/projects/ros-bridge/en/latest/ros_installation_ros2/)

Comment: I think I'm having this problem because I'm reading a rosbag produced by someone else. I don't have carla installed on my cpu. I was wondering if there was a way around.

Comment: @Jerry yea, not having it installed is the issue and unfortunately there isn’t a super easy way around. You need the message definition files so rosbag knows how to translate the data into a message.